# get online friend list using facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to get all online friends of logedIn user of my app using facebook sdk,
i have done some R&D but no use of it.
though i am asking all related permissions but my code doesnt work,please correct me were i am going wrong.

log cat shows "App does not have permission to make this call"

below is my code
permission list

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
            .asList("publish_actions" ,"user_likes","friends_likes","manage_pages","publish_stream","user_status", "user_online_presence", "friends_online_presence");

public void getOnlineFreindList() {
        Log.i("inside", "requestfriend()");
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
         if (session != null)
         {
          List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions(); 
          if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions))
          { pendingPublishReauthorization = true; 
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest   newPermissionsRequest = new Session .NewPermissionsRequest(this,PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
          }

        String fqlQuery = "SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1  ="+"100006508492702"+")";

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
        //Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                                "Online Friend Result: " + response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(Facebook.this, response.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

        // init();
        // requestMyAppFacebookFriends(session);
         }
    }
```

how to get this done ,thank you

Comment: Please call `session.openForRead()` to set the permissions

Comment: know code is working, but no data ,12-03 23:58:47.215: I/FacebookActivity(24139): Online Friend Result: {Response: responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false} when i runed fql query in graph api it workd there

Comment: This is because the user didn't grant the permission to your app.
You need to run the app again and make sure the permissions are asked when users is logged in for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the list of online and idle users.

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, online_presence FROM user " +
                  "WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') " +
                  "AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
                   ORDER BY name";
```

**UPDATE**

Please add `friends_online_presence` & `user_online_presence` permission

Comment: please check my edited questions, logcat shows App does not have permission to make this call

Comment: know code is working, but no data ,12-03 23:58:47.215: I/FacebookActivity(24139): Online Friend Result: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
when i runed fql query in graph api it workd there

Comment: Hi Sunil, i have issue with online friend.The issue is when i login with developer account its showing all the friend who are in online.But when i login with different account then it showing only developer account  is online(if it was online) and for remaining all friends its showing offline even some are in online.

Answer (score 0):

You need the **user_status** permission to read the user's status and **user_online_presence** and/or **friends_online_presence** permissions for the **online_presence.**

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) is the full permissions list.

Along with this it requires a FQL query--- SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())