# Facebook online friends

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Fql query to get online friends.The issue is when I log as developer account (developer account means:the account from which I generate facebookID), I get all the friends list who are in online but if I log in as different account then I get only developer account as in online (if dev Acc is logged in facebook), and for remaining friends is shows all are offline. The permissions I gave are `user_online_presence`, `friends_online_presence`, `user_status`.

And the query I used is

```
SELECT name,uid  FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name desc
```

Comment: Use this code may it help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368549/get-online-friend-list-using-facebook-sdk-in-android

Comment: Also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081932/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-facebook-online-friends-list

Comment: Iam using the same code as in above links.stil iam getting the issue.